# How can I render some js and keep it unobtrusive at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, unobtrusive-javascript

I have something like this in my Project#show view:

```
...
<p>
  <b>Start date:</b>
  <%= @project.start_date %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>End date:</b>
  <%= @project.end_date %>
</p>

<div id="calendar_view">
</div>
```

And I have the following in my projects.js.coffee:

```
$ ->
    $("#calendar_view").datepicker({
        inline: true
    })
```

The thing is, I would like to instantiate the datepicker with some relevant information ( such as the span of the project in months, restrict it to the beginning and end of the project ). Is there a way to mix some ruby, or the actual project's data inside the coffeescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my projects, I typically add an additional `yield` block to the end of our documents, right before the closing body tag.

```
<body>
...
<%= yield :additional_javascript %>
</body>
```

This way, in views, I can append *less* obtrusive JavaScript to the end of the document via a `content_for :additional_javascript` block:

```
<p>
  <b>Start date:</b>
  <%= @project.start_date %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>End date:</b>
  <%= @project.end_date %>
</p>

<div id="calendar_view">
</div>

<% content_for :additional_javascript do %>
  $(function () {
    $("#calendar_view").datepicker({
      some_property: <%= @project.some_property %>,
      inline: true
    })
  });
<% end %>
```

Comment: this will not be interpreted as coffeescript.

Comment: Using something like https://github.com/markbates/coffeebeans , and surrounding it with `coffee_script_tag` works though.

Comment: Apologies for the mixture of scripts, please consider the above to be pseudo-code. I meant to convey intent, not functioning code.